# Install4J - hide .jar file from installation directory?

Tags: install4j

I am currently working on turning my java application into a windows installer, converting the .jar into and .exe file.
Have chosen Install4J because of the ability to bundle JDK with the application, as well as recognizing previous installations when deploying updates.
Only problem I have, is the fact that the jar file for the application, is saved in the installation directory as well.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I don't want the original jar file in the directory, just the converted exe file.

Answer (score 1):

The .exe file is just a launcher for the JVM, it does not contain natively compiled Java code.

The best way to protect your code is to use an obfuscator like ProGuard.